# This in TypeScript arrow definitions?

Tags: typescript

I wrote such object literal in TypeScript:

```
var object = {
    message: "Say",
    say: () => {
        return this.message;
     }
};
```

And I got such generated JavaScript:

```
var object = {
    message: "Say",
    say: function () {
        return _this.message;
    }
};
```

Shouldn't there be such line before return statement:

```
 var _that = this;
```

as I am using arrow function expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. It's missing the :

```
var _this = this;
```

This is discovered after the release(0.8) and is currently fixed on the developer branch.

Note:
Also I think you wanted to write

```
var object = {
    message: "Say",
    say: function () {
        return () => this.message;
    }
};
```

which will actualy print Say when it's run. 
See: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:arrow_function_syntax

Answer (score 2):

`=>` is a bit of a danger here because, critically, it **binds `this` to the enclosing scope's `this`**. In the correct code generation, the `var _this = this;` line goes *above* the object literal and your `say` function simply returns `undefined`.

You only ever want to use `this` in a `=>` expression when you actually want to refer to `this` that would be present in the enclosing scope. In this particular case, you don't (you want the interior scope `this`, i.e. the object literal itself).